# How to center a button with margin in android layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

In the android layout I want to have two rows:

1. In the first row ONE button centered in the middle of the screen on top. Ledt and right to it some space.
2. A row of other buttons below that firs button with some distance.

Below is the code I tried to use. For the first `LinearLayout` I tried `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` as well as `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`, and I put a line `android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"` in the `LinearLayout` *and* the first `Button`. I have used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264465/how-can-i-create-2-rows-of-buttons-in-android-layout-xml-file) as a template.

However, there is no vertical space between the buttons in the first row and the second row, and the first button in the first row (on top) is on the *left* side of the screen. I thought I did put the right attributes in the `xml` file, but probably it is much more complicated. As always...

Here is the code of the full `xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/list_ok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="@string/ok"
            android:onClick="buttonEndStat"
            >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/header_list"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listname"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.225"
            android:layout_below="@id/list_ok"
            android:text="@string/headerName">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listok"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:text="@string/headerOK">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listnok"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:text="@string/headerNOK">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listhist"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:text="@string/headerHist">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listprandom"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:text="@string/headerP">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listphist"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.075"
            android:text="@string/headerH">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listptot"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.075"
            android:text="@string/headerProb">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listproc"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.075"
            android:text="%">
        </Button>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/header_list"
        >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would remove the first LinearLayout, and just leave the button itself centered horizontally on screen and with some margin (I assumed the root element is a LinearLayout):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/list_ok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/ok"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            >
        </Button>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/header_list"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listname"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.225"
            android:layout_below="@id/list_ok"
            android:text="@string/headerName">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listok"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:text="@string/headerOK">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listnok"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:text="@string/headerNOK">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listhist"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:text="@string/headerHist">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listprandom"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:text="@string/headerP">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listphist"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.075"
            android:text="@string/headerH">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listptot"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.075"
            android:text="@string/headerProb">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listproc"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.075"
            android:text="%">
        </Button>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/header_list"
        >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you want to keep your first LinearLayout remove the attribute `layout_gravity` from it and add `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` to the button to center it horizontally.

**EDIT:**

If you use a RelativeLayout as the root element, you have to specify each children positioning. You forgot to position your "header_list" below your top row:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_row"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/list_ok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="@string/ok"
            android:onClick="buttonEndStat"
            >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/header_list"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_row"
        >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listname"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.225"
            android:layout_below="@id/list_ok"
            android:text="@string/headerName">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listok"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:text="@string/headerOK">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listnok"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:text="@string/headerNOK">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listhist"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:text="@string/headerHist">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listprandom"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:text="@string/headerP">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listphist"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.075"
            android:text="@string/headerH">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listptot"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.075"
            android:text="@string/headerProb">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listproc"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.075"
            android:text="%">
        </Button>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/header_list"
        >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

To center your button horizontally, add `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` to its parent.

Comment: I have fixed the question; I thought I have put all the xml, but some parts were missing

Comment: I tried some combinations; I removed the LinearLayout around the button in the first line, and now I have vertical space between the button in the firstt row and then buttons in the second row. The first button, however, is still not centered horizontally

Comment: Your problem is you're using a RelativeLayout as a root element, and you have to specify how the children will be positioned. If you try my first answer, I'm pretty sure it will work for you, anyway I will edit it now for you to see how it should be done with your RelativeLayout.

Comment: I found a solution for the RelativeLayout: I had to change to `android:layout_width="match_parent"`, now the first button covers all the space, but this is fine....

Comment: @Alex, If you want to have 2 rows, one below another, it will be to use LinearLayout with vertical orientation instead of RelativeLayout.